# Avoiding out of memory error and clearing heap in java recursive functions

Tags: java, recursion, heap-memory

I am having a recursive function in java.Currently i am breaking out of the exception at some point in the recursive function by generating an exception.
The problem is i am getting heap overflow . Is there anyway to clear the unused variables in the heap once i break from recursive function using recursion.

```
public void recursivefun(int k)
{
 int m=1;
 System.out.println("m is "+m);
 if (k>100)
 {
  throw new Exception();
 }
 else
 {
  recursivefun(k+1);
  }
  System.out.println("after recursion");
}
```

I am starting each time k from 1. And i cannot use return because i dont want to go back to recursion at this time.I want to break out of the full recursion.

Comment: Why throw an exception instead of just calling **return** to get out of the recursion?  What are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: Or are you throwing an exception, as an **assert** ?

Comment: i am just breaking out of the whole recursion by throwing the exception.

Comment: Why not just **return** ?

Comment: Can you post complete program . What's the value k you are passing?

Comment: return will not exit from the full recursion

Comment: this code does not demonstrate the problem of "heap overflow"  (What is that actually?)

Answer (score 0):

M and K are locals variable, M is unused. So, are you sure there is a heap problem? Can you post the K value? 
Try to use return to exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like that code, it should not be a heap overflow, it can be an stack overflow if the condition has been set to a big integer, because in recursion function stack is engaged and not the heap, the question or code is not clear enough,

but I suggest is not bad to take a lock at  [enter link description here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/08/28/jvm-memory-model-structure-and-components/)